# How to error check pyppeteer page.goBack()

Tags: python, error-handling, chromium, pyppeteer

How would I error check if there is a previous page for the chromium browser to go to? I have a button which freezes out if the chromium instance has just been launched and there is not a previous page to go to using the command page.goback()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and is not intended behavior. You should consider reporting it as an issue on the GitHub repo.